# how can i stop an image from resizing at a certain browser height / width

Tags: css

Here's the CSS script.

```
img {
  max-width: 50vw;
  width: 50%;
}
```

So, here's the situation [code example](https://jsfiddle.net/2mhxf79o).

1. Resize the bottom right square's width until you see the bottom of the image exactly at the bottom of the page.
2. Now, reduce the width until you notice the bottom of the image is shorter than the bottom of the page.

What I want is for the image to stop resizing once it's height hits the bottom of the page so that when it's made smaller a scrollbar appears.

I thought that max-width might be the answer to this problem.

Comment: I lost you at: *"once it's width hits the bottom of the page"*

Comment: Sorry - I meant *height* as the width adjusts to make the image hit the bottom of the page.

Comment: what about `height: 100 vh;` ? (and remove width parameter)

Comment: I need to maintain a proportion given by the width being 50vw

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly you want:

- Have an image 50% width of the parent (so when the window shrinks the image also shrinks).
- Stop shrinking the height as an arbitrary moment.
- Maintaining the image proportions when doing this.

In this case, I'm afraid you can't do that because is just not possible reducing the width of image and maintain the proportions without reducing also the height. You have to decide if it's better for you having the image always at 50% size or having with the height that you want (I suppose that distorting the image is not an option).

But if you just want have the image as tall as possible maintaining the proportions just follow the suggestion of the comments and fix the image height leaving the width in auto.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rLz0rzxx/)

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 5px;
}

#image-container {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: calc(100vh - 10px); /* change as needed based on your margin/padding */
}
#image {
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div id="image-container">
  <img id="image" src="http://cdn.shopify.com/s/files/1/2152/0639/products/LR3A7988.jpg?v=1504299407">
</div>
```

Comment: What if I use max-height: calc(100vh - 166px); instead of max-width: 50vw.. how would i stop the image from resizing at this point @media (max-height 50vw) 
  { }

Comment: What do you what to achieve? Having an image as tall as possible but with some vertical margin, and with a height not less than the half of the viewport?

Comment: I have an image with a height that is fine at 800px - id like it to stop resizing as browser --  if height of the BROWSER screen (h) is less than (w/2), stop scaling/shrinking and start using scroll bar, - so, i have this @media (max-height 50vw)

Comment: I think finally get it, what you are trying doesn't work because it will set the maximum height *always* at 50vw, no matter what is the height. From your explanation you want a conditional rule based in the relation of the current width and height of the browser window, and you can't do that using only CSS as far as I know (although I think that you can do that using JS).

Comment: Can't I just add a "min-height: variable;" to keep it from shrinking any longer as according to       max-height: calc(100vh - 166px);
  width: auto;
  height: auto;

Comment: I found a workaround, it's not exactly was you want but I think is closer. You can use the `vmax` unit for using the current max dimension, using it for the `min-height` gives the image scroll bars when the height is lower than the adjusted width, see [updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rLz0rzxx/1/). Tell me if this similar to what you have in mind. One minor problem: Edge doesn't support `vmax`in the current version, but it's supported in the last preview version.

Comment: Awsome - getting close to a solution - can you show me how to do the vmax situation with a max-height: max-height: calc(100vh - 166px);

Comment: Yes, but 166px is a lot of offset, the image will look small [in the JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rLz0rzxx/3/), but it should look fine in the full browser window. Note also that in this case you don't need to use `max-height`, just `height` because you are using relative units.

Comment: Not exactly what I wanted.. I figured adding a min-height that is the value that the image has as a height the moment before w/2

Comment: I told you that this was a bit different, if you want conditional height it can't be done only with CSS, you have to use JavaScript.